# Dart Angular 5 router child redirectTo needs parent parameter

Tags: angular-dart, angular-dart-routing

We need to redirect a child route to another child route and maintain a parent route parameter. For example redirect the route `/u/2/object/123` to `/u/2/list`. Routing (for this simplified example) is handled by parent and child `RouteDefinition` levels. The parent definition would be

```
RouteDefinition(path: 'u/:index', component: ...
```

The child would be

```
RouteDefinition(path: 'list', component: ...
RouteDefinition(path: 'object/:id', component: ...
RouteDefinition.redirect(path: '.*', redirectTo: 'u/:index/list')
```

Running this returns error `FormatException: :index` so parameters in redirectTo URLs don't seem to be currently supported. Relative routes are also not supported.

We are using Dart Angular 5 so `RouteDefinitions` must be defined and given to the `router-outlet` before any of the router events fire. This seems to preclude use of procedural redirection at the child level. Are there any other solutions other than overriding the top level router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a component that only redirects in its `CanActivate` handler. The child `RouteDefinition` uses a component instead of a `.redirect`:

```
new RouteDefinition(path: '.*', component: RedirectTo.RedirectToNgFactory),
```

I have `RoutePath` definitions:

```
final user = new RoutePath(path: 'u/:index');
final list = new RoutePath(parent: user, path: 'list');
```

The component's `CanActivate` handler is given the route path and parameters. It always does a `router.navigate`:

```
@Component(
  selector: 'redirect-to',
  template: '',
)
class RedirectTo implements CanActivate {

  final Router router;

  RedirectTo(this.router);

  Future<bool> canActivate(RouterState current, RouterState next) async {
    router.navigate( list.toUrl(parameters: next.parameters) );
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I deployed a similar mechanism for logged in vs. logged out destinations in my app ... not obvious but has proved a solid way to redirect.